# How to specify dynamic invocation target assertion in Spock

Tags: java, groovy, spock

Consider this example

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class Foo{
  private AHandler ahandler;
  private BHandler bhandler;


  public void handle(String what){

     if(what.equals("A")){
          ahandler.handle(what);
     }else if(what.equals("B"){
       bhandler.handle(what)
     }else throw new RuntimeException();
  }
}
```

Now I try to test if-logic where given input proper handler must be called and nothing else, however I don't know how to specify assertion dynamically. Following does not work (but I think shows the intention)

```
def ahandler=Mock(AHandler);
def bhandler=Mock(BHandler);
def service=new Foo(ahandler,bhandler);

when:
   service.handle(input);
then: 
   1 * expectedCalls
   0 * _ //no other calls
where:
input | expectedCalls
"A" | ahandler.handle("A")
"B" | bhandler.handle("B")
```

Is it possible to do such thing with Spock?

Answer (score 1):

As usual, after some try and error (and googling and checking out github spock issues) I have found satisfying solution.

```
then: 
   1 * this."$handler".handle(_)
   0 * _ //no other calls
where:
input | handler
"A" | "ahandler"
"B" | "bhandler"
```

Answer (score 1):

While your own solution works after fixing your faulty and fragmentary sample code, I do not think that this over-engineered solution is very nice.

### Antonio's solution

First, your original code assumes that you have methods `AHandler.handle(String)`, but `BHandler.handler(String)` with an "r" at the end of the method name. The Spock spec assumes the same. Then, in your own answer you switched to a uniform `handle(String)` method for both handler classes, which probably makes more sense, but would have been impossible to solve like that, given your question.

It is also quite ugly that we need the explicit leading `this.` in `this."$handler".handle(_)`. This solution also breaks down, as soon as you move the mock definitions from fields to local variables in the feature method. Therefore, the solution is brittle. Anyway, here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing both your problem and your solution:

```java
class AHandler {
  void handle(String s) {}
}
```

```java
class BHandler {
  void handle(String s) {}
}
```

```java
class Foo {
  private AHandler aHandler
  private BHandler bHandler

  Foo(AHandler aHandler, BHandler bHandler) {
    this.aHandler = aHandler
    this.bHandler = bHandler
  }

  void handle(String what) {
    if (what.equals("A"))
      aHandler.handle(what)
    else if (what.equals("B"))
      bHandler.handle(what)
    else
      throw new RuntimeException()
  }
}
```

```java
import spock.lang.Specification

class DynamicInvocationTargetTest extends Specification {
  def aHandler = Mock(AHandler)
  def bHandler = Mock(BHandler)
  def service = new Foo(aHandler, bHandler)

  def test() {
    when:
    service.handle(input)

    then:
    1 * this."$handler".handle(input)
    0 * _  // no other calls

    where:
    input | handler
    'A'   | 'aHandler'
    'B'   | 'bHandler'
  }
}
```

### Somewhat more elegant solution

Instead, you could do this and even use local variables for mocks:

```java
import spock.lang.Specification

class DynamicInvocationTargetTest extends Specification {
  def test() {
    given:
    def handlers = [ A: Mock(AHandler), B: Mock(BHandler)]
    def service = new Foo(handlers['A'], handlers['B'])

    when:
    service.handle(input)

    then:
    1 * handlers[input].handle(input)
    0 * _  // no other calls

    where:
    input << ['A', 'B']
  }
}
```

Or, assuming that both handler classes implement a common interface, we can devise a more type-safe solution:

```java
interface MyHandler {
  void handle(String s)
}
```

```java
class AHandler implements MyHandler {
  @Override
  void handle(String s) {}
}
```

```java
class BHandler {
  @Override
  void handle(String s) {}
}
```

Now, my IDE automatically interprets `def handlers` as `Map<String, MyHandler> handlers`, and the warning for the unknown invocation target for `.handle(input)` call goes away.

Of course, if the field definitions in `Foo` would have type `MyHandler` instead of `AHandler` and `BHandler`, some more warnings could be removed from the Spock spec, but that is out of scope, and maybe you need the exact types there anyway. I am aware of the fact that your code is just sample code. I just wanted to point out ways to solve this problem without parsing strings to resolve method names.

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJytU01P4zAQvedXjLg0WUWh5YKEuohG7Go5VEjADVXIdSaphWMH201BqP99bSdOCt3lsNqb7ffefLwZN4Q-kwqhwExTta2faqINqkwbC8gWVcnlLns5P59Nz2bTWRSxupHKgG4kfc44EVV23yBlJaPEMCmiiHKiNVy_CVIzeiNa2QEPRFVoHlAbwFeDotDwQQjvEdgqSjCWEif-ClCxFsWFPzpsQ0TBUWn4Do-wuIClLSJe_OpekxTy_ikPTysvPT1dkmZ-bxQTVQrLtx69_Nd4rhSNqmUUrVLgDn5KGYdgj5PFZJXCeM0nqyTywt0mdNPLs44VM9FsTU8yA2kG38YwnrL6JHCsqWU9uSZBSJBWrYASzvWQUmEXzmtgPgdXYQquLvu-j_ZhaLYL73ujWEsMQnACSH84wIIlsA6YBZ0NR6L0mBvGazZMZ4FnrTzI04PrEVyP4N4layUrenvibra2WWJCbFZC7O4ZvmwJ1_HJ4iTpDIMhT3DT6zyGXOOxNB-l6y-lPclslNz5xbjbCsNq_PFKsXFrHifBcibsPyuJXaFhIX3lf2hLJ-OMBnvtR-RYozD6U4CrW_ttFSvwb8Hg_WDm-f-K9xvoeVw1).

### Cosmetic variations on my solution

**Update:** I revisited this code, because I was toying with another problem, wondering if we could do without the map and without repeating the `'A'` and `'B'` literals all over the place in a DRY way. This is one of them:

```java
class DynamicInvocationTargetTest extends Specification {
  def test() {
    given:
    def handlers = [Mock(AHandler), Mock(BHandler)]
    def service = new Foo(*handlers)

    when:
    service.handle(input)

    then:
    1 * handlers[index].handle(input)
    0 * _  // no other calls

    where:
    index | input
    0     | 'A'
    1     | 'B'
  }
}
```

Somewhat more esoteric, avoiding the `index` data variable and exploiting the Spock 2.0 `iterationIndex`. I am not recommending this variant, merely mentioning it for completeness's sake:

```java
class DynamicInvocationTargetTest extends Specification {
  def test() {
    given:
    def handlers = [Mock(AHandler), Mock(BHandler)]
    def service = new Foo(*handlers)

    when:
    service.handle(input)

    then:
    1 * handlers[specificationContext.currentIteration.iterationIndex].handle(input)
    0 * _  // no other calls

    where:
    input << ['A', 'B']
  }
}
```

Please note how both solutions use the spread operator for calling the constructor `new Foo(*handlers)`. Now that we have an ordered list of mocks rather than an unordered map, using the spread operator is safe.

Comment: hander->handle obvious typo, I was "coding" directly in SO question form.

Comment: Allright, I can see what you did there - define map of handlers and cherrypick from that map by the key. Slick

Comment: If it was a simple typo, why did the method names in the class under test and the test exactly correspond for both handler classes, before you edited the question a few hours ago? It looked as if it was on purpose, not coincidence. Anyway, programming in Stack Overflow is always a bad idea. Someone with your reputation should know better than to post questions with code untested locally. Back to the topic at hand: The question was in fact interesting, and I do hope that my answer sheds some light on possible alternatives to your approach. 

Comment: As I said, it was a typo as it were supposed to have common interface. The point of the question was how to "select" the inocation target. And yep Iv corrected it since you have pointed out the mistake. Shouldnt I do it?

Comment: If you put it together with the solution I have came up with you will se that method name is constant - and such was my intetnion here.

Comment: Ofc typo is on me, sorry for the confusion that it caused.

Comment: Please note my update with two cosmetic variations on my solution. It is mostly a not to myself for future use, but maybe it helps others, too.